# Why reprojection GeoJSON with new.ol.View - not working?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, geojson, coordinate-system

I try to reproject GeoJSon file in `OpenLayers` 3 from :

- [Geojson link](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.15.1/examples/data/geojson/countries.geojson)
- With these JS in head :

  ```
  <script src="js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.15.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.15.1/build/ol.js"></script>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.2.1/proj4.js"></script>
  ```
- With this code to set the new ol.View with
  newProjCode :

  ```
  var newProjCode = 'EPSG:27700'
  proj4.defs(newProjCode, '+proj=utm +zone=31 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs');

  var newProj = ol.proj.get(newProjCode);
  var fromLonLat = ol.proj.getTransform('EPSG:4326', newProj);
  var newView = new ol.View({
    projection: newProj
  });
  map.setView(newView);
  ```
- But after setting that new ol.View i see only white screen.

**Where is the problem ?**

Comment: I am not good at reading JavaScript, but you are changing the view to a reprojected one but do you reproject the data as well?

Comment: @user30184 no i think that i want only change view projection. Or i must reproject data as well ?

Comment: Check also your proj4js definition. The official definition is different compared to the one you specify.`proj4.defs("EPSG:27700","+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.15,0.247,0.842,-20.489 +units=m +no_defs");` link here --> http://epsg.io/27700.js

Comment: @pavlos dont work, i use myself the EPSG 2065 with definition from spatial referece org for Proj4js. Issue is on other place i think.

Comment: check this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/9jef1z2L/. It is working fine although map is a mess as the projection you are trying to use is not covering the whole world but just a piece of the earth. But if you stuck within the UK area should be fine.

Comment: @pavlos i check your fidle but i see only white screen after i click Run your fidle.

Comment: sorry for that. check it back http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/9jef1z2L/

Comment: @pavlos Thanks a lot, that is awesome.  Will it works when i define my own proj4js parameters or own projection ?  I would like that user can change that parameters of projection.

Comment: It should work. Give it  try and if you stuck come back here ;). Glad to help my friend.

Comment: @pavlos Thanks i appreciate it a lot. I will try it tomorrow at 18:00. Iam not o the PC now.

Comment: @pavlos yes it is working but i must use the EPSG like EPSG :1 that isnt used in PROJ4.  Is there way to use this projection change on openlayers v2 and how to set the new view with another projection with click on button ?  Because there is more options to stylize and I can add there graticule and ect. Thanks